# Image is not loading until restart application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, configuration, static, upload

After upload an image to location `dataBaseTest\src\main\resources\static\uploads\` I can't display it on webpage, until application is restarted. I know it's because folder `static` is loaded only when server is starting, but how can it be solved? I've tried to upload image directly to `\dataBaseTest\target\classes\static\uploads\` and it is working fine (loading immedietaly after upload), but it's just not seems to be correct. Also I tried to add

```
<configuration>
    <addResources>true</addResources>
</configuration>
```

to "pom.xml" but nothing has changed.

I've also tried to use  `addResourceHandlers` but whole folder `static` seems to stop working.

I'm using Spring boot dev Tools, so the app is restarting automatically, but I'm trying to solve it without any restart.

~ edit

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnWod.png)

~ edit 2

I'm running this app in intellij Tomcat.

this is my `FileUploadService`

```
public String uploadImage(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {


    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    Path uploadDirectory = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/uploads/");
    //Path uploadDirectory = Paths.get("target\\classes\\static\\uploads\\");


    try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
        String path = UUID.randomUUID()+ "-" + fileName;
        Path filePath = uploadDirectory.resolve(path);
        Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        return path;
    } catch (IOException ioException){
        throw new IOException("Error saving uploaded file: " + fileName, ioException);
    }
}
```

this is controller

```
public String displayArticles(Model model){
    final String currentName = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    System.out.println(currentName);
    model.addAttribute("currentUser", currentName);
    model.addAttribute("articles", repoArticle.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("comments", commentService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("likes", repoLikes.findByUsername(currentName));
    return "display_articles";
}
```

this is html

```
            <div class="image">
                <img th:src="'../uploads/' + ${article.path}" alt="">
            </div>
```

[folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owl6g.png)

Comment: you can certainly display your image without restarting your application. You must be doing something wrong.  What happens when you try to display your image? Does it not show? What http status code do you see under the Network tab ?

Comment: I checked few times and it's always 404 until restart. After restart it is automatically copied to folder `target`, so that's why it is working. But unfortunately i don't know how to skip this part.

Comment: are you running your app from an IDE or is it deployed on the server? I can see from that image that you're getting a 404 for a json resource, not jpeg? You haven't posted any code so we can only speculate as to why that happens.

Comment: ~ I update post one more time. Yes there is a json resource in code error and I don't know why, but after restart there is normal 200 code with jpg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should save your image directly to /target folder and thus make it immediately available (note that both the application resources and code are stored in /target when the app is running)

```
    //use the class loader to get the resource path, rather than hardcoding it
    final String uploadLocation = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("static/uploads").toString();
    //we should get rid of file:/, hence the substring
    final Path uploadDirectory = Paths.get(uploadLocation.substring(6, uploadLocation.length()) );
```

The rest of the code can remain the same.

Alternatively, you can specify your own upload folder. For instance,

**application.properties**

```
 #user home should be present on any computer
 files.upload.location=${user.home}/myApp/fileUpload
```

You would then simply retrive it in your controller,

```
 @Autowired 
 private Environment environment;
...

final String uploadLocation =    environment.getProperty("files.upload.location");
```

Hope this helps.